# ruby builder: can't generate xml tags like <fu-ba:r>

Tags: ruby, xml, builder

Hy Folks
I got the Problem that i have to create an xml in ruby with builder, running on a sinatra server.
The Xml is filled with xml tags like this one:

```
<fu-ba:r test="test1" source="h1">
  somthing
</fu-ba:r>
```

now i don't know how to get builder to create a tag like this one (the attributes are no Problem).
i Tried:

```
xml.fu-ba:r(......)
xml."fu-ba:r"(.......)
xml. << "fu-ba:r"(......)
```

Every idea or solution would help a lot, thanks Folks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ruby identifiers are consist of alphabets, decimal digits, and the
>   underscore character, and begin with a alphabets(including
>   underscore). There are no restrictions on the lengths of Ruby
>   identifiers.

Since [ruby identifiers](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html) don't allow the use of special characters builder has a method called `tag!` for this very purpose.

For example

```
x.tag!("fu-ba:r") {
  x.text! "something"
}
```

Outputs

```
# <fu-ba:r>
#   something
# </fu-ba:r>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Benji, thats exactly what i was searching for